# Matplotlib, 3rd set of values as colors of colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have **3 sets of values**. It's like I have the x-y coordinate plane which constitutes first two sets of values. And I have divided the plane region into *small squares* of unit size or some size in particular. Then I have another **2-D array** that contains **values corresponding to each square or small region**.

*Now, the problem*:

I could plot the 2-D array as color points using a colorbar but the x axis and y axis how the column and row indices respectively! Rather than that I wanted to have x and y coordinates shown. I tried searching a lot and didn't get the solution.

It is similar to [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo_dropped.html). It's just that I want my set of x-y coordinate values instead of the row and column values shown.

Please help. And suggest improvements if needed through comments instead of downvoting. That is very discouraging.

**EDIT:**

After following the answer provided, I got this
[image].

Instead I should have got the figure like this. Of course the axes as the previous figure and unlike below.[image]

Comment: Isn't that what [`pcolor(X, Y, C)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) does?

Comment: can you please give an example. I am really not comfortable with the docs written like in the link you provided.. please

Comment: I can't give an example in the comment. But if you provide examples of `X`, `Y` and `C` in the question, as well as describe specifically the desired result for those values, then I or someone else may be able to provide a more confident answer.

Comment: Ok. I am on it. But can u help me as how to give you the array of 50*50 values here? any link I should use or follow?

Comment: I'd just suggest to make it 5x5.

Comment: Yes. I was doing that, when the answer came up. And it almost solved my problem. But the figure is squeezed along vertical axis. How to fix that?

Comment: @MycrofD: it may be a problem of the order you do things. First `imshow` then `axis('normal')` and only after that `colorbar`. Look at the edited example code below. If you cannot make it work, please show the code.

Comment: @MycroftD: Please not that my comment above contained a hideous error, I edited it. The correct command is `plt.axis('normal')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have something similar to the `imshow` example you linked to but with different coordinate axes, you may want to use the `extent` keyword of `imshow`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some random data (10x10)
image = np.random.uniform(size=(10, 10))

plt.figure()

# draw the pixel image
#   interpolation='nearest': draw blocky pixels, do not smooth
#   cmap=pl.cm.gray: use gray scale colormap (autoscale, no vmin or vmax defined
#   origin='lower': draw first row of the array to the bottom if the image
#   extent=[-3,3,-10,10]: draw the image so that it covers area (-3,-10)..(3,10)
plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=[-3,3,-10,10])

# this is needed to make the pixels non-square if needed
plt.axis('normal')

plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

This way you can create "pixels" whose size is exactly what you want:

[image]

Of course, you may plot more information onto the same plot if you want just by using `plot` or something else.

The `image` here is an array of scalars and the colouring is defined by the `cmap`, but it may also be an array of RGB or RGBA values if you want to do fancier coloring. For example:

[How to create colormap of confidence estimates for k-Nearest Neighbor Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434485/how-to-create-colormap-of-confidence-estimates-for-k-nearest-neighbor-classifica/24435689#24435689)

If you want to have transparent areas in your map, put `nan` values into `image`.

Comment: Almost got what I needed..
But now, the y axis is shrunken. How to elongate it?
I mean x varies from 4 to 22. And y varies from -75 to -70.5. So the prob is it looks like a rectangle with the figure having squeezed along vertical axis, i.e. y axis.

Comment: @MycrofD: The `extent` keyword gives the size of the image in the plot area coordinates. Remember to give the `plt.axis('normal')` and then you can scale the axis ranges to be what you want by `plt.axis([-100,100,-50,50])` or whatever range you want to have.

Comment: thank you very much. Thnx to you and @Lev Levitsky for such a quick response. :)

Comment: I was using cbar.ax.set_ylabel('something'). It is not working. I can't label the colorbar. Help plz..

Comment: @MycrofD: Are you sure you want to set the Y label for the colorbar? That works well with `ax.set_ylabel`. But if you want to set the Y axis tick labels manually, you need `get_yticks().to_list()`, edit the list and `set_yticklabels`. The process has several kinks, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/matplotlib-modify-tick-label-text

Comment: cbar = plt.colorbar()..
cbar.set_label('something')..

I did that and it works. :)